# Is it possible to disable type inference in certain situations?

Tags: generics, rust, type-inference

I wrote the crate [`as_num`](https://crates.io/crates/as_num) which does "checked casts" between primitive numeric types. A "checked cast" is an analog to Rust's built-in checked addition. In `--debug`, a checked cast ensures that you can convert the result back to the original type without loss (i.e. truncation does not alter the numeric value), while in `--release` it should compile to a simple `src as dest`.

To achieve that, the crate offers a generic method `as_num` for primitive types that can be used to cast between types:

```
take_i32(2u8.as_num()); // 2 will be converted to i32 successfully
take_i8(12345u32.as_num()); // asserts at runtime since 12345 does not fit into an i8
```

This allows you to call `as_num` without stating the destination type, inferring it instead. You can explicitly state the destination type using `as_num::<dest>()`.

When a cast is guaranteed to succeed (according to [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/casts.html)), I would like the programmer to not have to bother with stating the destination type and let type inference do its work. If we have a (possibly) truncating cast, the programmer should be required to write the destination type.

Is this possible to achieve without resorting to two different function names, i.e. with only `as_num`?

Comment: Just to be clear: in your example, the user would have to state the destination type in both lines, right? Because on the type level, we obviously can't know the values of the variables. And on type level `usize` -> `i32` has the potential to change the value.

Comment: Inference is effectively disabled in Rust when it is *ambiguous*. An example is `.collect()` which regularly requires annotation because the receiver is otherwise unconstrained. I am not sure if one can easily create an ambiguity only in some circumstances, and I am not sure it is actually desirable. From an interface point of view; I think I'd rather have two functions.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Very good point! I'll adapt my example.